# Print index of the specific search result on the console

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

```
driver.navigate().to("https://maps.mapmyindia.com/");
Thread.sleep(3000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='onboarding-popup-sec']/div/div/button")).click();

File src = new File("D:\\Screenshots\\CityList.xlsx");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
int rowcount = sheet1.getLastRowNum();

for(int i=1; i<=rowcount; i++) {

    String str = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
    fis.close();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='auto']")).clear();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='auto']")).sendKeys(str);
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    By mySelector = By.xpath(".//*[@id='asa']/div[2]/span");
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(mySelector);

    int count=0;
    for(WebElement e: elements) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(e.getText());

        if(e.getText().toString().equals(str)) {
            System.out.println(count);
            sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(1).setCellValue("Pass");
        }
        else {
            sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(1).setCellValue("Fail");
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(src);
    wb.write(fos);
    fos.close();
}
```

In this code, I am opening Chrome and navigate to a map site through selenium and give an input of a field from an Excel sheet. In the search field on the web, it shows some auto suggestions and I want to get the index of the matching result from the list and print it in the console.

In the above code `if(e.getText().toString().equals(str))` this line is not executing or something so the index is not printing.

Please help!

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your exact requirement , have a look

Comment: Did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Below code match the exactly string that you search for from the search suggestion.

Try This:

```
    driver.get("https://maps.mapmyindia.com/");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='onboarding-popup-sec']/div/div/button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='input-group']//input[@id='auto']")).sendKeys(placeToSearch);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    List<WebElement> elements = driver
            .findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='as-results']//li[@class='as-result-item search-res']"));

    boolean match = false;
    int count = 0;
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        count++;
        String text = element.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='search-item']/span")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
        int index = text.indexOf('<');
        text = text.substring(0,index);
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(placeToSearch)) {
            System.out.println("Index of the element is " + count);
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!match) {
        System.out.println("Could not find the match in the result");
    }
```

Comment: 6
Agartala Airport
Usha Bazar Gandhigram Tripura 799009
Agartala
Tripura
Ginger Hotel Agartala
79 Tilla Agartala Tripura 799006
CHOUDHURY TRADERS
Agartala Assam Highway, Shibnagar, Dhaleswar, Agartala, West Tripura District, Tripura- 799007
boxanagar
,Agartala,Tripura
CP321278
Banamalipur B.K.Road Agartala Tripura,       this is the result when i gave Agartala as one of the input, i need index of Agartala only from the list.

Comment: thanks a lot, just one problem it prints index of the element incorrect, when i search Agartala, it prints 1 but the actual index of Agartala is 2, same with other results like when i search Agra it prints 2 but the actual index is 1.

Comment: @shivam , Still facing problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> list = div.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
Thread.sleep(5000);
int listsize= list.size();
for(int i=0;i<listsize;i++)
 {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
      if(list.get(i).getText().contains("Nehru Place"))
      {
       System.out.println(i+"=index of Nehru Place");
      }
}
```

Am getting following output:

Nehru Place

New Delhi, Delhi

**0=index of Nehru Place**

Eros Hotel New Delhi

Nehru Place, New Delhi, Delhi

**1=index of Nehru Place**

S2
Nehru Place, New Delhi, Delhi

**2=index of Nehru Place**

902
Nehru Place, New Delhi, Delhi

**3=index of Nehru Place**

901
Nehru Place, New Delhi, Delhi

**4=index of Nehru Place**

903
Nehru Place, New Delhi, Delhi

**5=index of Nehru Place**

Nehru Place Epicuria
26, Nehru Place, New Delhi, South District, Delhi- 110065

**6=index of Nehru Place**

Nehru Place
Karnal,Karnal District Haryana

**7=index of Nehru Place**

rrd.net.in

Comment: thanks but i want most desired index of the element which matches the string completely, like when i give input as Nehru Place then it would give the index of that result which is completely matched and occur first in the search result

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.get("https://nehruplacedealers.com/");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='onboarding-popup-sec']/div/div/button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='input-group']//input[@id='auto']")).sendKeys(placeToSearch);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    List<WebElement> elements = driver
            .findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='as-results']//li[@class='as-result-item search-res']"));

boolean match = false;
int count = 0;
for (WebElement element : elements) {
    count++;
    String text = element.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='search-item']/span")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
    int index = text.indexOf('<');
    text = text.substring(0,index);
    if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(placeToSearch)) {
        System.out.println("Index of the element is " + count);
        match = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!match) {
    System.out.println("Could not find the match in the result");
}
```